# all ionic 2 app shows me the same page DHIS 2 routine and surver data on your pocket

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

weird issue happen me just, i'm trying to run my project and i saw other app with this photo
[image]

i opened a new project, even change the file directory and see the same image.
is this any issue with ionic 2??

Comment: let's keep it short. No.

Comment: what? so what the problem? all my old app and any new app opened me the same project

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but Ionic isn't. Googling for 'ionic 2 dhis2' shows this question as first result with no other relevant links. Seems like you're the only one with this problem since I just did the same (create new project) and I didnt see this.  This question is missing a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by clear cache in chrome.